# Counting Combinations of Hats and Scarves: Experiments with the "Power Set" (2^n)

Tags: combinatorics

I thought of the following problem:

- Suppose there is a store with 2 baskets: The first basket has 2 hats (red hat, blue hat) and the second basket has 2 scarves (black scarf, white scarf). Note: Not 2 types of hats and 2 types of scarves, but literally two hats and two scarves - the store only has 4 items.
- Over the course of a day, 3 people visit this store. Person 1 enters the store buy something and then leaves the store. Person 2 enters the store and buys some items from what Person 1 didn't buy, and then leaves the store. Person 3 then enters the store and buys some items that Person 1 and Person 2 didn't buy.
- It is possible that Person 1 buys everything and leaves nothing for Person 2 and Person 3 - it is also possible that none of the 3 people buy anything.
- Once an item has been purchased, no other person can purchase this item.

**My Question:** If someone were to compare the purchases made by all 3 people - how many different combinations could the hats and scarves been purchased in?

I tried to make the "tree diagram" to count all the possibilities. For simplicity, I call the "red hat" as "A", the "blue hat" as B, the "black scarf" as "1" and the "white scarf" as "2" (e.g. 0,AB = no scarf and both red hat and blue hat) but as we can see, this diagram becomes very big (I could not even fill in all the "branches"):

[image]

**Thus - do we have any mathematical formulas we can use to count the total number of combinations in this problem I thought of?**

I know of something called the **"Power Set"** which can be used to count "all subsets of a set including the empty set and the set itself" (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Power_set) :

[image]

This means that if there "n" items, they can be counted in 2^n different ways. I understand that this formula can be used to calculate all combinations for hats and all combinations of scarves separately (I assume you can multiply these together): 2^2 * 2^2 = 4 * 4 = 16 combinations:

[image]

But I am not sure how the above formula can be adapted to fit my problem in which fewer items exist as you move "across the tree".

**Is there a way to derive a formula that can be adapted for a generalized version of this problem?**

As an example - suppose there are 5 People, and each new person enters the store only have the previous person has left and can buy items not purchased by all previous people - and suppose there are:

- "m" number of hats
- "n" number of scarves
- "p" number of shoes
- "j" number of pants

How many combinations can these people fill their baskets?

Thanks!

Comment: If all items are distinct, then for $n$ items and $x$ shoppers you have $(x+1)^n$ ways to distribute the items.

Comment: Seems to me there are four items for sale, and the distinction between hats and scarves is superfluous. You're asking for the number of ordered triples of disjoint subsets of a four-element set.

Comment: As @Daniel has discovered, each of the $n$ items can go to any one of $x+1$ places, the places being the $x$ shoppers or no one at all.

Comment: @ Daniel Mathias: Thank you for your reply! Does (x+1)^n include shoppers buying no items? Does this formula work for any amount of items (e.g. as @ Gerry Myerson mentioned, perhaps the distinction between hats and scarves is indeed superfluous?)? Does this make sure that once an item has been purchased by a shopper, another shopper can't purchase the same item?

Comment: @ Gerry Myerson: thank you for your reply! I will have to read some more - what are "ordered triples"?

Comment: Yes, $(x+1)^n$ includes everything you ask.  Each item can wind up in $x+1$ places-the hands of $x$ shoppers or still on the shelf.  Each location is selected independently of the other items, so you multiply the number of possibilities.  See Wikipedia on the multiplication principle.

Comment: @ Ross Millikan: Thank you for your reply! Is this what you are referring to? https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rule_of_product

Comment: In the end, I would still be interested in knowing why (x+1)^n correctly corresponds to this problem.

Comment: Think about it for half a second, will ya? There are $n$ items, right? Each item can go to any of $x+1$ places, right? So by the most elementary rule of counting, the number of possibilities is $x+1$ times itself, $n$ times – that's $(x+1)^n$. If you don't believe it, or don't understand it, make up an example, just pick some numbers for $x$ and $n$ (but not too big!), and write out all the possibilities, and count them up, and think about how you can arrange them to conform with the $(x+1)^n$ formula. Think!

Comment: So, have you got it now, stats?

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because OP has abandoned it.

Comment: @ Gerry: Hello! Sorry for the delay in reply! I have been still thinking about this question and trying to understand the logic behind it... unfortunately, I have still not fully understood it, and will have to accept this formula as fact. thank you for all your help!

Comment: OK, let's try this one more time. In the original problem, you have four items. Let's call them items a, b, c, and d. Now, item a can go to any one of four places; it can go to the 1st person, or to the 2nd person, or to the 3rd person, or it can remain at the shop. Regardless of what happens to item a, item b can also go to any one of those four places. So, for each of the four ways of disposing of item a, there are four ways of disposing of item b, making $4\times4=4^2$ ways of disposing of items a and b. And for each of those ways, there are four ways of disposing of item c (continued...)

Comment: making $4^2\times4=4^3$ ways of disposing of items a, b, and c. Finally, for each of those $4^3$ ways, there are four ways of disposing of item d, making $4\times4^3=4^4$ ways of solving the problem of disposing of all four items. I hope that's clear. Then the same logic, applied to $n$ items instead of four, and $x$ customers instead of three, leads to the formula $(x+1)^n$. I don't think I can make it any plainer than that.